# Is there a way to get the first and second object from an api response and compare them in ASP.Net core MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, api

I am trying to get the closing value from the first and second object from my api response and compare them and then display the a string depending on the comparison on the html page

(I have removed my personal api key and replaced it with 'your_api_key')
The response I am getting from the api is as follows;

`{"Response":"Success","Type":100,"Aggregated":false,"Data":[{"time":1548191280,"close":1.13,"high":1.13,"low":1.13,"open":1.13,"volumefrom":0,"volumeto":0},{"time":1548191340,"close":1.13,"high":1.13,"low":1.13,"open":1.13,"volumefrom":0,"volumeto":0}],"TimeTo":1548191340,"TimeFrom":1548191280,"FirstValueInArray":true,"ConversionType":{"type":"direct","conversionSymbol":""},"RateLimit":{},"HasWarning":false}`

I have tried to use an if statement but I am getting errors, I believe the problem lies in how I am trying to access the list

Currencies.cs

```
public class DatumEurUSD
{
    public double CLOSE { get; set; }
    public double HIGH { get; set; }
    public double LOW { get; set; }
    public double OPEN { get; set; }
    public string MOVEMENT { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObjectEurUSD
{
    public List<DatumEurUSD> Data { get; set; }

    public double OldUSD { get => Data.First().CLOSE; set => OldUSD = value; } // value of USD one minute ago
    public double NewUSD { get => Data.ElementAt(1).CLOSE; set => NewUSD = value; } // current value of USD


    if(OldUSD == NewUSD)
    {
    DatumEurUSD.Movement.set("NONE")
    }
    else if(OldUSD > NewUSD)
    {
    DatumEurUSD.Movement.set("DOWN")
    }
    else if(OldUSD < NewUSD)
    {
    DatumEurUSD.Movement.set("UP")
    } 

}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Currencies()
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=EUR&tsyms=USD,JPY,GBP,CHF,CAD,AUD,NZD&api_key=your_api_key");

        var reqEurUSD = WebRequest.Create(@"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=EUR&tsym=USD&limit=1&api_key=your_api_key");

        //var reqEurAVG = WebRequest.Create(@"");

        var r = await req.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var rEurUSD = await reqEurUSD.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        //var rEurAVG = await reqEurAVG.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var responseReader = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream());
        var responseData = new JsonTextReader(responseReader);

        var responseReaderEurUSD = new StreamReader(rEurUSD.GetResponseStream());
        var responseDataEurUSD = new JsonTextReader(responseReaderEurUSD);

        //var responseReaderEurAVG = new StreamReader(rEurAVG.GetResponseStream());
        //var responseDataEurAVG = new JsonTextReader(responseReaderEurAVG);

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        var d = serializer.Deserialize<RootObjectEUR>(responseData);
        var dEurUSD = serializer.Deserialize<RootObjectEurUSD>(responseDataEurUSD);
        //var dEurAVG = serializer.Deserialize<RootObjectEurAVG>(responseDataEurUSD);

        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.Eur = d.EUR;
        mymodel.EurUSD = dEurUSD.Data;

        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

Currencies.cshtml

```
@model dynamic
<h1>Most Common Currency Exchanges</h1>

<table border="1">
<th>Currency</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Movement</th>
<th>Open</th>
<th>Close</th>
<th>Date</th>
<tr>
    <td>EUR/USD</td>
    <td>@Model.Eur.USD</td>
    <td>@Model.Data.MOVEMENT</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>@DateTime.Now</td>
</tr>
```

I am currently currently getting an error in my if statement for invalid token and the variables do not exist in the current context.

I would like the @Model.Data.MOVEMENT to display the correct string according to the if condition.

Comment: r u sure that the json are de-serialized correctly and the Data  property has members, what is the value of d after this line 
 var d = serializer.Deserialize<RootObjectEUR>(responseData);

Comment: @MostafaELite I am concentrated on var dEurUSD and after debugging this variable it has been de-serialized correctly. (var d I have working as wanted)

Comment: What error/s, does your code even compile?

Comment: @EdSF "invalid 'if' in class struct or interface member declaration" and also "the name 'OldUSD & NewUSD' does not exist in the current context. It does not compile

Comment: Yes, I'd advise you to _[first learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1519)_ based on your question and comments (too broad of a topic hence the link). Hth